# How to change Automated alias settings on module install?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, pathauto

Situation:

- Drupal 6 node module defining custom content type
- Necessity to have an automated alias for the content type, e.g. `content_type/[title-raw]`

Question: How can I programmatically set the Automated alias setting of the new content type to the above pattern in the `hook_install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is trivial, automated alias patterns of Drupal are stored in variables:

```
function hook_install()
{
    variable_set('pathauto_node_[content_type]_pattern', 'content_type_path/[title-raw]');
}
```

where `content_type` refers to the machine-readable name of the content type and `content_type_path` is the desired prefix of the alias of the content type.

The solution was fetched from the post at http://drupal.org/node/1246334#comment-5038566

Comment: This is correct. I would add: that you should wrap the variable set in a module_exists test or make sure that pathauto is required by the module.

Comment: Yup, I solved it with "dependencies[] = pathauto" line in the module.info file.